# Stored Procedure Header Comment Generator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any script available that automatically generates header comments for stored procedures header including author, change history, parameter list.

**Update 1**: What the correct name for the "Stored Procedure Header Comment"?

Here are a few examples of header comments
[SQL comment header examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085672/sql-comment-header-examples)

I expect such tool exists. I think the name "Header Comments" is not the actual name, that is why google search does not help.

A better "Google Searchable" name could be the answer.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @RobertColumbia, I have more than 30 stored procedures that I need to add header comments to them. That is lots of work and can be easily automated by using a template or text generator. In my opinion, I should not spend the time (and charge money) to type so many repetitive text. That is not right ting to do. What would be an acceptable way to ask for others experience in SO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is out of the box in SSMS. Just press Ctrl+Alt+T, choose from the list within `Template Browser` and modify by adding your name, parameter list, history, etc.

Comment: Does that add comments to existing stored procedures? I have more than 30 stored procedures that I need to add the header comments.

Comment: Nop. these are just templates for new ones. For existing ones you can extract them, add headers/comments and ALTER or Re-Create.

Comment: @AllanXu: That metadata might not be available or inaccurate. Especially so if the object has been modified more than once since creation.

Comment: What do you mean? Extract CURRENT texts of all procedures, modify them and ALTER them.